# Троичный поиск для упорядоченного массива

Tags: алгоритм, поиск

Суть: есть массив элементов, и для поиска элемента в нём нужно применить троичный поиск. Однако везде в интернете имеются лишь алгоритмы для функции (причём она должна **сначала возрастать, а затем убывать**) и ни одного алгоритма для массива ... Как мне адаптировать алгоритм для этого случая?

Comment: Какой "троичный поиск"? Вы о чем? Че-то не понял... Чем не устраивает простой пробег по массиву и поиску нужного элемента?

Comment: О, так здесь еще и упорядоченный массив же, а значит вместо O(N) можно применить [бинарный поиск](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA) за O(log N)

Comment: Не устраивает тем, что в условии задан именно троичный поиск. И ещё надо проверить, насколько он быстрее того же бинарного.

Comment: Тогда при чем здесь "поиск элемента", если надо искать экстремум? И массив точно упорядоченный? Если так, то что мешает применить тот же троичный поиск для поиска экстремума, задав граничные условия, чтобы не выйти за границы массива. Тогда поиск закончится именно тогда, когда начнут нарушаться эти граничные условия. Правда в этом случае непонятно что искать - максимум или минимум, т.к. есть и то, и другое. Может просто оригинальная задача немного по-другому сформулирована?

Comment: Задача: определить, есть ли в массиве элемент или нет. Повторить 5 раз для эл-тов, которые есть, и для эл-тов, которых нет. Алгоритм поиска - троичный поиск (который препод назвал "третичным")

Comment: ну ок, в чем тогда проблема? берете двоичный поиск и меняете в нем разбиение исходного массива с двух равных частей на две части из отношения 1:2 и будет вам счастье

Comment: У меня была такая мысль, но я не уверен, что она правильная.

Comment: @Byulentу стоит спросить у препода. Возможно, он под "третичным" поиском подразумевает что-то свое.

Comment: @Byulent: «троичный поиск» — это какое-то не очень широко известное понятие. Вы хотите адаптировать непонятно (нам) какой алгоритм для того, чтобы он делал непонятно (нам) что. Мы вряд ли сможем вам помочь без дополнительной информации.

Comment: @Byulent, насколько мне известно это примерно то, что Вы предполагали. Отрезок на котором ищется величина делится не точно пополам (как в двоичном поиске), а пропорционально отличию искомого элемента (ключ, с которым сравниваете) от элементов на границах отрезка. Т.е. для очередного сравнения  выбираете элемент в массиве ближе к тому концу отрезка,  от которого менее отличается искомый элемент. (надеюсь все же хоть что-то в моем тексте понятно...)

Comment: Для поиска экстремума в упорядоченном массиве поиск вообще не нужен, достаточно взять крайний элемент. Поэтому речь может идти только о поиске заданного значения.

Answer (score 1):

Есть вариант поиска, который можно назвать троичным - это когда используются варианты "меньше", "равно" и "больше" (есть такие задачи на взвешивание монет). Похожую конструкцию имел оператор IF в языке Фортран, когда за выражением следовали три метки.

Выразим идею троичного поиска с помощью несуществующей условной конструкции вида

```
ift (expr) ? {<} : {=} : {>}.
```

Если размерность массива  **a** меньше **bb = 2<sup>n</sup>**, то алгоритм для определения номера элемента в массиве может быть таким:

```
i=0;
for (b=bb/2; b>0; b/=2){ 
    aa = a[i+b];
    ift(x - aa) ? {} : {i+=bb; break;} : {i += b;}
}
```

Таким образом, троичный поиск экономит одну итерацию.